# how to implement Northwind in Django

Tags: mysql, django, northwind

I am trying to implement Northwind database model in MySQL using Django-admin for displaying data. Does someone know how to do it "clean" way from original model? Is there any functional implementation to download (models, admin)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Totally untried procedure follows. Not sure what you mean by 'clean'. Here's a few things on the internet that might help:

Step 1 - export from Access to MySQL:

http://www.geeksengine.com/article/export-access-to-mysql-4.html

Step 2 - point django at the database and use inspectdb to create models.py

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb

Step 3 - clean up models.py, run syncdb, add it to the admin, see what you go.

Step 4 - ask this guy if he ever managed it:

http://ifdebug.com/django-northwind-coming-soon/ - he's had four years!

Comment: excelent :D thanks, but about Step 4, if you see there only one comment is from me and he did not responded yet. I will try it by my self with your cook book. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ouykjh/northwind_management/

I managed to create models for Northwind Database.

Just clone the repo. Make sure that settings.py are set.

Enter postgres -> create database named 'mydb' (as in settings.py).

Hit python manage.py syncdb - it will create tables with relations.

Enter postgres -> psql mydb

hit 
\i inserty.psql

Inserts are here(https://github.com/ouykjh/northwind_management/blob/master/inserty.sql#L11)

Hope it works :)